# c++ how to downcast from upcasted derived

Tags: c++, inheritance, upcasting, downcast

I have a class named "package" which is the base of the derived "shader_package".

The package instances generally get exclusively generated in a function called load. It has a pointer to package as a return parameter. Therefore I can also return every class derived from package due to inheritance. However, when passed the type information is lost (correct?) and I cant actually know anymore afterwards what the original class was.

In my case, however, this shouldnt be a problem. The stuff returned by the loader is supposed to be used in a class constructor or assignment operator, that then uses the info in the correlating package derivertive to initialize its member variables.

How can I do this properly, without having to use a union or variant type?

EDIT:

Some pseudo code illustrating what I want to accomplish

```
class package{
//actual contents are not relevant. The base doesnt have any virtual functions. Only data
}
.
class shader_package:public package{
private:
    shaderData data;
public:
//getters setters and other standard stuff. Not really relevant
}
.
.
package* import(const char* path){
    string extension = getExtension(path);
    if(extension == ".shader"){
        shaderData data;
        //somehow populate shaderData
        return new shader_package(shaderData);
    }
    /* Check for other types and return other derived packages*/
}
.
.
.
main{
    shader nShader(import("pathToShader"));
    /*Do stuff with it*/
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] illustrating the issue, it's not completely clear from your description

Comment: If you're saying that you know for sure what derived type you have, then you can just `dynamic_cast` (or `static_cast` if you're **really** sure!).

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm not sure that an MCVE is terribly helpful here - but some code or pseudo code showing what the OP is trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: If you need to know exact type of the object referenced by a pointer to basic class, then you have something wrong in your design. Try to refactor it so that you do not need to check the type of the loaded package.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks  that worked. Please post as an answer!